# Android Private Certifiacte in Rest Service

Tags: java, android, ssl, x509trustmanager

My App works with many Restservices with different Certificates.
I open a `HttpsURLConnection` and that's working fine.

But now 3 Servicepoints have a private root CA, so I get an Trust anchor for certification path not found Error in my App.

How can I make the App automatically get the certificate from this servicepoint?

I don't want to create a Trustmanager that ignores SSL errors.

Comment: that is a selfsigned certificate?

Comment: No its from a certification firm

Comment: ok, i think that is not a well known CA, right?

Comment: Yes is a ca certification

Comment: Yeah but read here https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa "In this case, the SSLHandshakeException occurs because you have a CA that isn't trusted by the system. It could be because you have a certificate from a new CA that isn't yet trusted by Android or your app is running on an older version without the CA. More often a CA is unknown because it isn't a public CA, but a private one"

Comment: The Certiciat is from GlobalSign and they say its a global CA, and i dont have any private key

Comment: They say that Android trust their certs automatically?

Comment: in android the globalsign is in the trustet cert list. The Cert is a clobal ca. And also Chrome / Firefay say the cert is ok and save, only the android https connection have a problem with that